# How get back reverted files to working space?

Tags: git

Say I have the following commit tree:

```
a->b->c->revert b->d->e
```

After commit c, I find commit b has problem, so I revert b using `git revert b`, then commit d and e come in.

Now I want to get code changes of commit b back to my local working space, so that I can fix the problem and recommit it.

My question is, how can I get the code change of commit b back to my local working space?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to apply any commit with [git cherry-pick](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html)

Answer (score 0):

Revert the commit that reverted `b`.